# How to display a specific date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this SQL Query running on SQL Server Management Studio 2008:

```
  SELECT  ItemId,
    DATEADD(HOUR,-4,CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT([Date],8)+' '+
                    SUBSTRING([Date],10,2)+':'+
                    SUBSTRING([Date],12,2)+':'+
                    SUBSTRING([Date],14,2)+'.'+
                    SUBSTRING([Date],15,3))) [Date],
    [Object],
    SourceSite,
    DestSite
   FROM (  SELECT  ItemId,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(18),[Date]) [Date],
            [Object],
            SourceSite,
            DestSite,
                        UserCode
    FROM JnlMediumMove) A
  WHERE UserCode = 'Automation'
  ORDER BY [Date] DESC;
```

This query dispays every date, however I am ONLY interested in the date that is 1 day before the current date.  So everyday reports can be sent out consisting of the day befores activities.

Answer (score 0):

if you add to the where clause :

```
and datediff(day, [date], getUTCDate()) = 1
```

The thing to note is the timezone of the UTC command is GMT.  So depending on the range of things you may need to date add hours to get the appropriate time zone.

Because your column isn't actual date try doing:

```
    and dateDiff(day, CONVERT(DATETIME,
                    LEFT([Date],8)+' '+
                    SUBSTRING([Date],10,2)+':'+
                    SUBSTRING([Date],12,2)+':'+
                    SUBSTRING([Date],14,2)+'.'+
                    SUBSTRING([Date],15,3)
                    ), getUtcDate()) = 1

And isDate( CONVERT(DATETIME,
                    LEFT([Date],8)+' '+
                    SUBSTRING([Date],10,2)+':'+
                    SUBSTRING([Date],12,2)+':'+
                    SUBSTRING([Date],14,2)+'.'+
                    SUBSTRING([Date],15,3)
                    )
           ) = 1
```

The whole query would be:

```
SELECT  ItemId,
    DATEADD(HOUR,-4,CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT([Date],8)+' '+
                    SUBSTRING([Date],10,2)+':'+
                    SUBSTRING([Date],12,2)+':'+
                    SUBSTRING([Date],14,2)+'.'+
                    SUBSTRING([Date],15,3))) [Date],
    [Object],
    SourceSite,
    DestSite
   FROM (  SELECT  ItemId,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(18),[Date]) [Date],
            [Object],
            SourceSite,
            DestSite,
                        UserCode
    FROM JnlMediumMove) A
  WHERE UserCode = 'Automation'
  AND dateDiff(day, CONVERT(DATETIME,
                    LEFT([Date],8)+' '+
                    SUBSTRING([Date],10,2)+':'+
                    SUBSTRING([Date],12,2)+':'+
                    SUBSTRING([Date],14,2)+'.'+
                    SUBSTRING([Date],15,3)
                    ), getUtcDate()) = 1

And isDate( CONVERT(DATETIME,
                    LEFT([Date],8)+' '+
                    SUBSTRING([Date],10,2)+':'+
                    SUBSTRING([Date],12,2)+':'+
                    SUBSTRING([Date],14,2)+'.'+
                    SUBSTRING([Date],15,3)
                    )
           ) = 1

        ORDER BY [Date] DESC;
```

Comment: It gives me the same error: Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: The problem is that the column [date] isn't of type date or datetime.  You have to be able to convert it if you want to use the date functions.  You can try converting the column or just adding to the where clause "and isDate([date]) = 1"  alternatively you can add another column is that of type date and then populate it with actual dates.

Comment: I added that to the where clause.  The query runs error free, however no data from the database is being displayed, it is empty.

Comment: The problem is that you don't have actual dates in the column.

Comment: Yeah the database was made a long time ago and they used numeric values as dates, but I have converted it with the query I provided in the question.

Comment: Can you add your suggested code to the code I have provided for you? I'm not sure where exactly to put the code you have suggested.  Thanks

Comment: This query is running fine, but I think the 4 hour time difference I accounted for in my code is causing a problem because now 90% of the entries are of June 23rd but there is a couple that are late night June 22nd.  Is there any way we can get around this?

Comment: Change the datediff line from to be: AND dateDiff(day, DATEADD(HOUR, -4, CONVERT(DATETIME,

Comment: Msg 174, Level 15, State 1, Line 18
The dateadd function requires 3 argument(s).

Comment: Is it possible for you to modify the code you have suggested so i can try running it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  ItemId,
DATEADD(HOUR,-4,CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT([Date],8)+' '+
                SUBSTRING([Date],10,2)+':'+
                SUBSTRING([Date],12,2)+':'+
                SUBSTRING([Date],14,2)+'.'+
                SUBSTRING([Date],15,3))) [Date],
[Object],
SourceSite,
DestSite
FROM (  SELECT  ItemId,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(18),[Date]) [Date],
        [Object],
        SourceSite,
        DestSite,
                    UserCode
  FROM JnlMediumMove 
  WHERE CAST(substring(convert(varchar(50), [Date]), 0, 5) + '-' +
  substring(convert(varchar(50), [Date]), 5, 2) + '-' +
  substring(convert(varchar(50), [Date]), 7, 2) AS DATETIME) = 
  CONVERT(date, DATEADD(day, -1, getdate()))) A --Converting to date again to remove the time part
WHERE UserCode = 'Automation'
ORDER BY [Date] DESC;
```

Comment: It gives me this error: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near 'A'.

Comment: I get this error now: Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.

Comment: What is the datatype of the `Date` column of `JnlMediumMove`?

Comment: It is Date(numeric(17,9), not null): 

An example: 20130623.143448060

Comment: It is running error free but no data is being displayed, it is just empty.

Comment: The query is running error free now, but instead of all the entries being on June 23rd there are some on here that are late night June 22nd.  Is there any way you can get around this?

Comment: I have a question,  how would the code look like If i wanted to split the Date column into two columns, one with the Date and one with the time (no seconds)